# Probablity of all different socks pulled out.

Tags: probability

There were 5 pairs of socks in a pile of clothes. On pulling out one by one and after pulling out 5 socks, I found they were all different. What is the probability of such an event?

Comment: are the pairs differentiated? ie, can some one realize that whichone is right sock and the other is left

Comment: No, socks of a pair are identical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of there are 5 pairs of socks or 10 socks so pulling out any 5 can be found out from the formula.

$C(10,5) = 252$

And the favourable outcomes will be only $2^5$ as of

Every pair has two socks and there are five pairs so you have select different so at first pull you have two choices of any pair and then again at the second pull it goes same.
So the probability becomes

$\displaystyle \dfrac{2^5}{252}=\dfrac{8}{63}$

Answer (score 2):

For randomly choosing $5$ socks from $10$ socks, we have $\displaystyle \binom{10}5$ ways. For choosing $5$ different socks, we have $2^5$ ways. Thus the probability is $\displaystyle \dfrac{2^5}{\binom{10}{5}}=\dfrac{8}{63}$

Answer (score 2):

A simple way is to use the [double factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial)  which will give

$Pr=\dfrac{10\cdot8\cdot6\cdot4\cdot 2}{10\cdot9\cdot8\cdot7\cdot6} = \dfrac8{63}$

The numerator skips pairs, while the denominator doesn't.

Comment: Interesting method!

Comment: So, in terms of percentage, it would occur 12.7% of times such an experiment is conducted?

Comment: That is the *expected* percentage  from conducting such an experiment .